# До какого момента хорош кэш к БД из  HashMap-ов?

Tags: база-данных, java, кэширование, коллекции

День добрый, уважаемые!

Как думаете, по каким причинам могут возникнуть сложности  при создании простейшего кэша к БД через HashMaps? Где предел такого простого решения?

Comment: Если вы пишете программу для себя, то непонятно, почему у вас возникает такой вопрос. 
Ксли вы занимаетесь enterprise разработкой, то непонятно, зачем вообще использовать "костыли" вроде кеша на `hashmap`, если это рано или поздно приложение "выростет" из кеша на `hashmap` и придется искать другой solution и тратить время на изменения кода. Так почему не сделать это сейчас? Возможно, вы немного потеряете в скорости, но взамен костылей будет использоваться готовая проверенная либа. А время лучше потратить на конфигурацию кэша.

Comment: Пожалуй, был слишком категоричен. ведь минимизировать затраты можно воспользовавшись `AbstractFactory` и сделав несколько реализаций внутреннего кэш менеджера: на `hasmap` и `3rd party` кэше.

Comment: jmu, такой вопрос возник т.к. в приложении которое мне досталось по наследству уже есть hashmap cash (синхронизированный, все ок), и мне хотелось бы оценить недостатки такого решения  - стоит ли разбираться во всяких коммерческих кэшах и переделывать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, сложности начнут возникать, если ваш кэш начнет работать в многопоточной среде. **HashMap** не thread-safety класс и поэтому нужно будет заниматься синхронизацией операций доступа к нему, либо использовать потокобезопасные коллекции.

Во-вторых, если ваше приложение потребляет много памяти, а кэш тяжеловесный, то может такое случится, что когда память начнет заканчиваться, GC не начнет удалять объекты из кэша. Поэтому необходимо будет реализовывать его на слабых ссылках(**SoftReference/WeakReference**).

В-третьих, если скорость поиска в кэше будет критична, то стоит задуматься о выборе другой реализации хэш-таблицы. **HashMap** реализует хэш-таблицу со списками, а это не самая эффективный структура при наличие большого числа объектов с одинаковыми хэшами.

Comment: Вы, видимо, неправильно выразились. Проблема как раз в том, что GC **не будет** удалять объекты из кэша на основе `HashMap`, когда памяти будет мало. И чтобы обеспечить работоспособность приложению ценой очистки кэша, нужно будет использовать слабые ссылки, например, <a href="http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html">WeakHashMap</a>

Comment: Да-да, именно так. Спасибо за поправку.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему так: если у вас есть редко изменяющаяся таблица из нескольких сотен (ну тысяч) строк на которую ссылаются другие таблицы, то хэширование с помощью LinkedHashMap или ConcurrentHashMap выглядит очень разумно и грамотно. Например - если это список стран или что-нибудь такое.

Скорость в любом случае будет ведь лучше чем если дёргать из самой БД (да и всё таки HashMap шустро работает, если только hashCode для объектов достаточно грамотно определён).

Если собираетесь кэшировать миллионы записей, то да, возможно вам захочется что-то другое.

Answer (score 0):

Принципиальные проблемы актуальности кэша возникают, если базу обновляют несколько приложений, не знающих друг о друге. В таком случае надо как-то отслеживать устаревание кэша.